# Bulk find & replace on Wordpress posts/pages (minus image paths)

Tags: posts, database, mysql, sql, blog

I'm dealing with a tricky issue and wondering if anyone has a good way to solve this. I am trying to change everything on my Wordpress site that has "2019" in my posts/pages with "2020", however when I do that, it is also changing my image paths as well, which I don't want.

If I just change my directory to 2020, won't that impact my SEO? That is the primary thing I am concerned about and don't want to have to keep renaming my directory every year. I am just looking to change everything but the image paths within posts/pages.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Via Velvet Blues Update URLs Plugin
You can also use the Velvet Blues Update URLs plugin. After installation, go to Tools> Update URLs. In the Old URL field we enter what we need to change, and in the New URL we enter what we need to substitute. As a result, you can change the permalinks from linking and to the site’s pictures, to relative ones.